# Adding Google Play Services causes error Conversion to Dalvik Format failed with error 1

Tags: java, android, admob, dalvik

My app was error-free,then I added the `Google Play Services` library to my app for using `AdMob`.I proceeded to make these changes to the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I also added an `Activity` as directed:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Then I added the following code to my `MainActivity`:

```
 AdView adView;
 adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3b9bdbbc9b1c3b30").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The value was previously defined in `xml` as:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY AD UNIT ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />
```

I have tried to uncheck `Force error when external jar contains native code`,`clean` the app and then run it.My app has three external libraries it is using:

```
1.tess-two
2.android-support-v7 appcompat
3.google-play-services_lib
```

I use the package `com.blutechnologies.scancard` for my app so that the classes are treated uniquely by the system.

I have a `SplashActivity` and `MainActivity` which might also easily be part of other libraries.Are they a cause of the clash or is there a clash between classes in `tess-two` and `google-play-services`

What caused this error and how can I fix it?

The console also has an error:

```
Dx trouble processing "java/sql/Savepoint.class":
```

The link to my `Order and Export` file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7fk3f31dz0vqq4/order_export.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link. It may help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308418/2586981

Also if you add the ad mob from xml, you need not add google play services.
All you need is to add a library file to your libs folder.
The jar file needed is "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar".

Hope this help you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you,removing the `android.jar` library helped me

Comment: Note that Admob is now packaged as part of Google Play Services. Amdob-6.4.1 was the last library *before* that change.